# When creating package version in SFDX I get the error: AppSwitcher: An unexpected error occurred

Tags: salesforcedx, packaging-2

When trying to create a package version using:

sfdx force:package:version:create -p "XRA2" -x -w 10  --loglevel=debug

I get an obscure error:

AppSwitcher: An unexpected error occurred. Please include this ErrorId if you contact support: 646587487-854713 (-1465083608)

I cannot figure out how to get any more information in order to pinpoint the problem.

My default is my Partner Business ORG. I can create scratch orgs, upload all the code and run it without errors.

Any help would be appreciated.

John Gibbons

Comment: You would need to contact support for details on the Gack error, but generally speaking, this is the result of one or more missing files (e.g. a tab or object that was not deployed).

Answer (score 1):

I took a look into backend logs and the actual error that's surfaced is

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Module does not exist locally nor does it exist globally, thus cannot resolve the originating org. on id AppSwitcher

This indicates that the metadata from which you are trying to generate the package version is missing proper metadata.

Search for `AppSwitcher` and delete all the references to it.

Comment: We had to explicitly forceignore the AppMenu and I wonder if this is a similar problem.

Comment: Thanks Mohith that fixed the problem, much appreciated. I would guess that it is related to Phil's comment.

Comment: Where exactly do see the backend logs? I am in similar situation and cant seem to find the solution

Comment: @nSv23 Only Salesforce support and the Salesforce authorized internal employees have access